# Download Common crawl complete index file

Tags: python, boto, common-crawl

The common crawl index file used in the below project

https://github.com/trivio/common_crawl_index/blob/master/bin/remote_copy

`mmap = BotoMap(s3_anon, src_bucket, '/common-crawl/projects/url-index/url-index.1356128792'`)

is a [partial one.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/common-crawl/EfR1YHvtWrY/ImnW7Z0rgq4J)

I want the complete index file(APRIL-2015 crawl data) to use in my project which uses the above project as a base.

Where can I download the entire index file?

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/common-crawl/partial$20index$20file/common-crawl/R0k5kjK63-c/8vwO4OWY5z8J) Tom Morris states that

> The index files which are used by the index service are also available
>   for download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common crawl index files are publicly available at `s3://commoncrawl/cc-index/collections/`

You can check out all the crawl indexes available by *aws command line*: `aws s3 ls s3://commoncrawl/cc-index/collections/`

Index files for April 2015 are at `s3://commoncrawl/cc-index/collections/CC-MAIN-2015-18/indexes/`

If you want to download index `*.gz` files via http protocol, you can do:

> https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/cc-index/collections/CC-MAIN-2015-18/indexes/cdx-00000.gz

cdx files are mostly from *cdx-00000.gz* up to *cdx-00299.gz*, so complete index is contained in 300 files.